# How to get or set any arbitrary type of object in C#

Tags: c#, object, casting, generic-collections

I have a class which shall act as a "model provider". Basically this is what it shall do:

The `ModelProvider` creates several objects, e.g. a `Project` and a `User`. The idea here is that from any part of my application I can call the `ModelProvider` to get the latest `User` or `Project`. Furthermore, from any part of the application I shall be able to push an updated `User` or `Project` to the `ModelProvider`.

Short: The `ModelProvider` shall be the class hosting the latest instances of `User` and `Project`.

**DRAFT**

```
class ModelProvider {
  private User user;
  private Project project;

  public ModelProvider() {
    this.user = new User();
    this.project = new Project();
  }

  public void SetModel(T model) {
    // If 'model' is of type User, do something like: this.user = model;
    // If 'model' is of type Project, do something like: this.project = model;
  }

  public T GetModel(???) {
    // Return the requested model. Either:
    // return this.user; or
    // return this.project;
  }

}
```

However I don't know how to actually get and set the requested model. Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Is the intent for the `ModelProvider` to have only _one_ of either `user` or `project` at any given time, but not _both_ at the same time? EDIT: Furthermore, are both of these objects inheriting from the same base class/interface?

Comment: If you don't know or care what the type of the model is, why don't you just have a single `model` field typed as `object` (or some other common base type of `User` and `Project`?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair No, the `ModelProvider` shall keep one instance of each at any given time.

Comment: Then how do you expect that the GetModel() method can determine wether it should return the user or the project?

Comment: @Eddy That's the question :-)

Comment: The fact you can't answer that is a good indication that this construction can't work like that. Your 'pattern' won't work. If you want advice from this population you will have edit your question and add what you are trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: I have reworked my question. Maybe it gets a bit clearer of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks strange what you are trying to do. A potentially better way is to provide designated methods, but that depends on what you are actually trying to achieve:

- `void SetUser(User user)`
- `User GetUser()`
- `void SetProject(Project project)`
- `Project GetProject()`

Comment: I think that calling this the 'correct way' is premature since the OP is very unclear about his intentions. To me it looks like he is trying to create some sort of generic wrapper object where he does not want to care if he is stuffing users or projects into it.

Comment: @Eddy: Agreed. Reworded my answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a generic class:

```
class ModelProvider<T>  // (optionally) where T: baseClassOfUserAndProject
{
    private T model;

    public void SetModel(T model) 
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public T GetModel() 
    {
        return this.model;
    }
}
```